# Importing eps files as layers in Gimp

Tags: gimp

I have been trying to create an animation using 300 eps files.
When I try to open all the 300 files as layers (File -> open As Layers),
a dialog box appears for each file with the heading "Import from Postscript" .

I have to click on "import" button for every image, in order import the images.

Is there a way to avoid the appearance of this dialog box for each image, because clicking "import" for 300 times is not at all a manageable task.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to add an intermediary passage (e.g. a [conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15084899/gimp-script-for-converting-eps-in-other-formats))? Could be more fast.

Comment: Yeah, it works without an issue with png images. Why this happens for eps is probably because GIMP doesn't recognize this format. I wanted to use eps because it's of better quality than png.

Comment: The problem is related to the parameters to be used to render the eps file (e.g. the size), which can't be passed [command line](http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Basic_Batch/) to Gimp. Once fixed the size, for the Gimp is the same start from an eps or a png. My suggestion is to split the processing in two: at first, render the eps file as png with an external program (Imagemagick, Ghostscript, Inkscape can be used command-line), and then import in Gimp all the png files. See also [here](http://www.gimptalk.com/index.php?/topic/53155-run-script-without-import-from-postscript-dialog-appearing/).

Comment: Yeah, That's probably the only option.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have GIMP-GAP (http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Using_GAP/) installed then you can use it to load your files.

1) Make sure that all of your frames are named sequentially[*] using a pattern such as "filename_0001.eps", "filename_0002.eps", "filename_0003.eps", ...

2) Open the first file using "Edit->Open" -- this will present you with the postscript settings dialog box. (You will only be presented this dialog once.)

3) Perform "Video->Frames to Image..." to convert the file sequence to a multilayer image.

[*] If your filenames aren't sequential, you can rename them using GNU BASH by running the following command in the directory containing the .eps files.

`f=(*.eps);i=($(seq -w 1 ${#f[@]}));for n in $(seq 0 $(expr ${#f[@]} - 1 ));do mv ${f[n]} frame_${i[n]}.eps;done`

Comment: Hi saul, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. Could you please enclose your code in ` backticks so it `looks like this`? That way, it's easier to see where it actually ends. Thanks! If you have any questions, please see the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!